# Creating non-UEFI USB Boot Media exclusively in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, usb, legacy, bios

So I was tasked with creating a script that allows an ISO to be copied to a USB easily using PowerShell. I made it error proof as possible. However, there is one place where I am stumped, and that is dealing with a Legacy BIOS. Right now, this works fine on UEFI. However, we have a few departments that still use a Legacy BIOS. This is not a Windows ISO, and I prefer to not have anyone download any additional software or packages.

I am sure the only thing that truly needs to be changed is the bootsect flags. However, when I used /nt52 and /mbr I am not able to boot the media.

```bsh
    $ISOPathforDeploy = "\\someshare\custom.iso"
    $PartitionType = "FAT32"
    ####################################
    #Please only change variable above. 
    #Do not edit code below this line.
    ####################################
    $Results = Get-Disk |
    Where-Object BusType -eq USB |
    Out-GridView -Title 'Select USB Drive to Format' -OutputMode Single |
    Clear-Disk -RemoveData -RemoveOEM -Confirm:$false -PassThru |
    New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -IsActive -AssignDriveLetter |
    Format-Volume -FileSystem $PartitionType
    $Volumes = (Get-Volume).Where( { $_.DriveLetter }).DriveLetter
    Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISOPathforDeploy
    $ISO = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Volumes -DifferenceObject (Get-Volume).Where( { $_.DriveLetter }).DriveLetter).InputObject
    Set-Location -Path "$($ISO):\boot"
    bootsect.exe /nt60 "$($Results.DriveLetter):"
    Copy-Item -Path "$($ISO):\*" -Destination "$($Results.DriveLetter):" -Recurse -Verbose
    Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISOPathforDeploy
```

Comment: For legacy boot you need to set your partition to active after you created it. In diskpart it is done with the command `active`, maybe

Comment: try `Set-Partition -IsActive $true` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-partition?view=win10-ps